# Error when using SUM intrinsic function

Tags: arrays, fortran, sum, fortran95

using the g95 compiler, I get an error that says:

```
ERROR: Procedure attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute in 'quantityarray'
```

I was trying to take find the total sum of the array. Here is the subroutine in which this error appears:

```
SUBROUTINE findTotals(pricearray,quantityarray,totalprice, totalquantity)

INTEGER, INTENT(IN)::quantityarray
REAL, INTENT(IN):: pricearray
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)::totalquantity
REAL, INTENT(OUT)::totalprice


totalquantity = SUM(quantityarray)
totalprice = SUM(pricearray)


END SUBROUTINE
```

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: SUM requires an array. Shouldn't the quantityarray be an array?

Comment: yeah it's supposed to be an array, and I had it be SUM(quantityarray(size)). with 'size' being passed in and intent in, but i still get an error saying: "Function 'SUM' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type" which doesn't make sense b/c sum is supposed to be an intrinsic function.

Comment: Writing `SUM(quantityarray(size))` doesn't magically make quantityarray an array; you have to specify that in its declaration (maybe you made this change as well). Also, `quantityarray(size)` only selects the last element of the array, not the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program SummingAnArray
implicit none
integer, dimension(10) :: array=(/ (i, i=1,10) /)
integer :: i, Total

call VectorSum(array,Total)
print *,Total
read(*,*)



contains
    !===================================================
    subroutine VectorSum(Vector,Total)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in), dimension(:) :: Vector
    integer, intent(out) :: Total

    Total = SUM(Vector)
    end subroutine VectorSum
    !===================================================
end program SummingAnArray
```

Is this perhaps what you wished to achieve?